# Where in the arterial system is the blood pressure intended to measure?

Tags: blood-pressure

I've seen the blood pressure consistently being defined as the pressure exerted by the blood onto the outer wall of the blood vessel.

However, the arterial system branches, changes diameter, and varies in distance from the heart, so surely the pressure in, say, the aorta is not anywhere near the pressure in the capillaries.

So my question is this, where in the arterial system is this number intended to measure?

Comment: What do you mean "intended to measure"? In what context?

Comment: @BrianKrause Blood pressure is intended to measure pressure exerted by blood on the wall of the vessels. Surely pressure is not uniform throughout the arterial system. I want to know where in the arterial system are we trying to measure the pressure.

Comment: No, blood pressure **is** the pressure difference relative to some reference point, typically the surrounding atmosphere. Blood pressure is not "intended to measure" anything, it's a pressure, a physical thing that exists. And yes, it is a physical thing that is not constant throughout the circulatory system.